# Most efficient way to fill byte array with data?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte

I am trying to fill a byte array of 64KB with data (any data will do... could be random but does not need to)

what is the most efficient way of doing this?  Here is my current code, but I have a feeling this could be done a lot better:

```
 Dim dataByte() As Byte
 dataByte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("long string goes here")
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly 64kb? Interesting. You could consider how large primitives are.

Remember that each character is a single byte. Therefore to create 1024 bytes, we can make a string of length 1024 like this:

New String(char(0), 1024)

Adjust as needed.

Comment: thanks for the reply... not necessarily 64KB, but this byte array will be written to files, and 64KB is the largest cluster size in NTFS... but is this string to byte array the most efficient way of doing it? thanks.

Comment: At the end of the day, data is data. Unless you're doing it over and over and over again, the performance difference should be irrelevant. If you are, try storing them as an array of integers instead. Integers are the 'least common denominator' of most languages and should require the least amount of processing time.